# New Certified Platform Developer II Exam

Tags: certification, platform-developer-2

On the new salesforce platform developer 2 exam I see a multiple-choice/multiple- select questions what does this meant? Also I don't  see any pass percentile like 68% or 73%? Do we still have the programming assignment for this new exam pattern?

[image]

Comment: I received my beta exam results today, so I imagine they will be updating the study guide with the passing score shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This certification program is still in beta - actually it's available to everyone from today, I got the email a couple of hours ago.

The reason this certification doesn't have a passing score is because Salesforce are still evaluating the responses from the beta participants. Based on the responses, Salesforce will lock in the final content of the exam as well as set the passing score.

I believe this will get updated very shortly, given that the beta participants still haven't received their results.

Here is the [FAQ](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-New-App-Builder-and-Platform-Developer-Credentials) page for the new certifications.

**Update:**

> The following exams do not provide immediate results because they
>   require evaluation by a team of experts:
>
> - Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II programming assignment
> - Salesforce Certified Force.com Advanced Developer programming assignment
> - Salesforce Certified Technical Architect review board

[Source](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Receiving-your-Exam-Results)

Comment: What about the current Dev 501 MCQ examination? I gave my first attempt for dev 501 MCQ in may and not able to clear it Now I'm planning to take the exam second time Is it useful when compared to this new Platform Certifications? or do I need to start taking this platform certifications?

Comment: "Effective September 14th, we will no longer be offering the Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer and Force.com Advanced Developer multiple choice exams to new applicants." - If you failed the first time, you'll have to take the new certifications now.

Comment: i still see the advanced developer exam for registration. Do you suggest to register for it or not?

Comment: I've heard from people that have already passed the multiple choice that they can't register for the assignment. You better off wait and do the new PDI/PDII